# Why I always got the same socket file descriptor with accept()

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am doing some coding with socket in C. Based on the basic code [socket.c](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/server.c) from Beej's book, [our code](https://github.com/pcyeol/socket/blob/server/server.c) is trying to accept multiple connections. We run server on one machine and two clients in different terminals in another machine. However, the server can not know to whom the message is sent to and sometimes the received message can be showed in one terminal while another terminal got no message.

It seems that the server now can not specify which client he wants to send message to. We put accept() in a while loop and found that in each loop the accept() returns the same socket file descriptor. It's weird since the two clients have different port so we thought we should got two different socket file descriptors.

Part of our code:

```
while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
        /*if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        */
        struct receive_para para;
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_t tid1;
        para.new_fd = new_fd;
```

Why the returned new_fd in each connection has the same value?

Comment: I assume that in the code you don't show us (i.e. in the parent) you close the `new_fd` descriptor? Then why *wouldn't* you get the same one in the next `accept`? You have two processes, they are independent, including their descriptors.

Comment: The kernel will always allocate to you the lowest filedescriptor slot available. If you fork for each new connection and then close the client socket in the parent, you'll always get the same filedescriptor number on each new connection (provided you don't open or close other fds before accepting the next connection).

Comment: The child process has the client's connection and should deal with it. The parent process can close `new_fd` right after `fork` and not care any more about it. If it does so, `new_fd` will have the same value each time, which is perfectly OK.

Comment: OT, referring the linked code: Here ^Referring he linked code: Here ^char message[]="";
fgets(message, MAXDATASIZE-1, stdin); send(new_fd, message, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);` you defined `message` to be exactly 1 `char` wide. Use `char message[MAXDATASIZE-1] = ""` instead. You probably also could drop the the `-1` here as well as when calling `send()`. Read the docs to `fgets()`.

Comment: OT, referring the linked code: Also you want to `0`-terminate the buffer inside `struct receive_para para;` you can easily do this by initialising the whole structure to all `0`s before using it: `struct receive_para para = {0};`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then we tried to not close it and it gave us a new value! Thank you so much!

Comment: @PSkocik Thank you!

Comment: @Gloria If you don't close the sockets you will have a *resource leak*. A process only have a limited number of sockets, and you can very easily run out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now I got more confused. What we want to do might be: new_fd is created and the child would handle the corresponding work. If the new_fd is closed, then later for a new connection we will always get the same value. If it is not closed, then we have some resource issue. So do you think we have a better choice or some better way to do that?

Comment: @n.m. No, it's not OK. We want to have more than one connections so we want to have many children and many new file descriptors. So if we close it, every time the new  connection comes, we will always have the same value, which is not what we want.

Comment: t looks like you want a new fd value for each connection. Do you care to specify a reason for that? Normally there isn't any. Unless your needs are very special and very different from those of a normal TCP fork model server, do what normal TCP fork model servers do, namely, close the socket after the connection is handed over to a child. The parent won't need it any more. and can reuse the fd number.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot. I want to do that because I want to have more than one connection at the same time. Just like we are chatting with different people at the same time. Or maybe there is some other better ways to implement that?

Comment: Your children processes handle client connections. Each child process is responsible for one client. Since there are many child processes, you may have many connections running at the same time. Your parent process only accepts connections and hands them off to the children. There is no reason to have more than one connection in the parent process, because the parent process only handles each connection for a very short time, just enough to accept it and hand it over to a child. Please note, this is how most fork model TCP servers work, yours has no reason to be different.